# Emacs failed quit with error of "utf-8 cannot encode"

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, emacs

I am running emacs-27.1 on windows 10 and encounter decoding problem when I try to quit emacs with C-x C-c.
Emacs stopped me from quitting and report error as:

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ‘ *temp file*’:
  (prefer-utf-8 (45 . 4194262) (46 . 4194268) (47 . 4194241) (48 . 4194297))
  (utf-8 (45 . 4194262) (46 . 4194268) (47 . 4194241) (48 . 4194297))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
  prefer-utf-8 cannot encode these:        
  utf-8 cannot encode these:        

Click on a character (or switch to this window by ‘C-x o’
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where ‘C-u C-x =’ will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

  raw-text no-conversion
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there does not exist such a buffer called  ‘ *temp file*’:

```
~/s/a/e/current/bin λ (buffer-list)
(#<buffer *eshell*> #<buffer *scratch*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-1*> #<buffer primate-org-agenda.el> #<buffer my-config> #<buffer todo.today.org> #<buffer CAPTURE-todo.today.org> #<buffer *Ibuffer*> #<buffer *doom*> #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*> #<buffer *Messages*> #<buffer  *code-conversion-work*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 0*> #<buffer  *Echo Area 1*> #<buffer  *code-converting-work*> #<buffer *helm-mode-load-file*> #<buffer  *which-key*> #<buffer  *Custom-Work*> #<buffer *helm-mode-basic-save-buffer*>)
```

Following the previous error report guideline to

```
             position: 371 of 819 (45%), column: 29
            character:   (displayed as  ) (codepoint 4194262, #o17777726, #x3fffd6)
              charset: eight-bit (Raw bytes 128-255)
code point in charset: 0xD6
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: L:Left-to-right (strong)
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 3fffd6"
          buffer code: #xD6
            file code: not encodable by coding system utf-8
              display: no font available

Character code properties: customize what to show
  general-category: Cn (Other, Not Assigned)
  decomposition: (4194262) (' ')

Here is a ‘help-xref’ button labeled ‘ ’.


There is an overlay here:
 From 342 to 379
  face                 hl-line
  priority             -50
  window               #<window 18 on *Warning*>


There are text properties here:
  button               (t)
  category             help-xref-button
  face                 link
  help-args            (" *temp file*" 45)
  help-echo            "mouse-2, RET: jump to this character"
  help-function        [Show]
```

[image]

Any ideas please to solve the problem?

Comment: *"How do I use a text editor"* is not a programming question.

Comment: `\326 \334` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Which character did you try to encode at all?

Comment: `#o326 #o334 #o301 #o371` is 周六 in GBK, `(decode-coding-string (unibyte-string #o326 #o334 #o301 #o371) 'chinese-gbk) ;; => "周六"`

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem on Linux: emacs 27.1 on Ubuntu 20.4 loading a PNG. It would not let me kill the buffer.

WORKAROUND

Switch off undo-tree-mode. undo-tree is writing at least some of the contents of the file to a temp buffer - *temp* on Linux, *temp file* on your Windows there - writing it to disk, killing the buffer and then not being able to clean up because of the encoding problem.